# Where can I find graphic artists who can draw clean Windows 7/Mac style icons?

Tags: website-design, images, graphics

Not sure if this should be a community wiki, but I'd like to find some graphic artists who can create beautiful Windows 7 icons (for use on the web)... somewhat similar in style to the image below.

Does anyone have suggestions on who has a similar style?

[image]

Comment: I made this CW, it really is asking for a list of resources.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Elance](http://www.elance.com/). Explain what you're looking for, just like you did here, and ask prospective designers to show samples of their work.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try http://99designs.com/ - I've used them for a logo or two in the past and they have an Icon section. At the very least its worth looking at.

Comment: +1 to 99designs.com. I've used their service for an icon for my Windows program and for the price ($383 total fees of which $300 went to the designer) I'm happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't let this site become Yellow Pages for companies - I fear this will be a messy Wiki where a few companies will profile them selves. [Google is better for this](http://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&channel=s&hl=en&source=hp&q=order+custom+icons&meta=&btnG=Google+Search).

Comment: I LOVE LGMTFY!... either way I would have never heard of elance before, perhaps I'll find more.  I'll leave it up to the moderators, since I'm a n00b  :)

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you on this - but given that my close vote is binding, I'd rather let the community decide on this. That said, I've removed your LMGTFY link in reference to the [meta discussion here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links)

Comment: @Farseeker point taken. @MakerOfThings7 sorry if I came across arrogant with that link.

Comment: No problem, I live in NYC and am not really sure *if* I can tell if someone is being rude anymore. I still think lmgtfy is funny, but since it's banned via meta, I won't use it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DeviantArt](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/icons/os/). Some of the best artists showcase their work there and I'm sure you'll be able to find someone willing to do work for hire.